# быстрое логическое ИЛИ двух векторов long

Tags: c++

Есть два вектора в1 и в2, задача получить третий вектор в3, каждый элемент которого равен логическому ИЛИ соответствующих элементов векторов в1 и в2. Размерности в1 и в2 равны.
Решение в лоб:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<long> v1(128, 1L);
    std::vector<long> v2(128, 2L);
    std::vector<long> v3(128, 0L);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        v3[i] = v1[i] | v2[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v3[i];
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Есть ли способ быстрее поочередного обхода каждого элемента?

Comment: Обычными методами - нет. Используя ассемблер - возможно mmx/sse расширение поможет. Возможно цепной lodsd stosd получится сделать оптимальнее.

Comment: Ну а контейнер обьязательно должен иметь тип вектор?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не обязательно, но размерность может изменяться.

Comment: Вряд ли - ведь в любом случае нужен проход по всем элементам. При очень больших векторах можно поиграться в распараллеливание...

Comment: Asm не подойдёт?)

Comment: Вряд ли, что-то можно найти быстрее: https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-or

Comment: Бесплатная для AMD: framewave.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Хватит думать за компилятор, он тоже умный.**

Напишем код и посмотрим на ассемблерный выхлоп:

```
using vec_t = std::vector<unsigned long>;

void vec_or(const vec_t& a, const vec_t& b, vec_t& c) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] | b[i];
    }
}
```

Результат компиляции (опции: `-O3 -mavx`): https://godbolt.org/z/v8lmGv

Насколько мне известно, команда `vorps` оперирует 128-битными числами. Это означает, что за одну операцию цикла честно обрабатывается 128 бит - это 32х `uint32_t` или 16x `uint64_t`! Разве этого мало?

Я немного схитрил и включил AVX-инструкции, но даже без опции `-mavx` (или аналогичной для других компиляторов), получается высокооптимизированный код.

Comment: Я думал, что есть асмовская команда, которая может за раз работать с блоками памяти разного размера

Comment: Команды есть, но мы же пишем на C++ :)

Answer (score 5):

`std::valarray` как раз делает то, что вам нужно: выполняет действие сразу со всеми элементами(это класс, наиболее оптимизированный для численных расчетов). Только у него аргументы конструктора в обратном порядке:

```
std::valarray<long> 
v1(1L, 128),
v2(2L, 128),
v3 = v1 | v2;
```

И все...

Comment: нет, так не работает :) Для валаррэй перегружены операторы, если посмотреть реализацию, то там будет макрос `_VALOP`, который разворачивается в `for (size_t _Idx = 0; _Idx < _Ans.size(); ++_Idx)`. За более изящный синтаксис спасибо, но вопрос про скорость.

Comment: я измерял, он быстрее